# How to get click event from markerclustererplus

Tags: jquery, user-interface, maps, markerclusterer

I implented markerclustererplus in my jquery script like this:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap({'streetViewControl':false,'mapTypeId': 'terrain'}).bind('init', function(evt, map) { 
    var mcOptions = {gridSize: 30, maxZoom: 15, ignoreHidden:true};
    $('#map_canvas').gmap('set', 'MarkerClusterer', new MarkerClusterer(map, $('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'markers'),mcOptions));
}); 
});
```

Everything is fine so far. The question is: How do i catch the click event, if user clicks on a cluster?

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem with the `'click'` event in addition to the two other Cluster class events `'mouseover'` and `'mouseout'`. There's a bug in the `markerclusterer.js` file for the latest version 2.0.15. To get it to fire the `'click'` event, change the `markerclusterer.js` as follows:

Find this line:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_, "click", function (e) {
```

And below it change this:

```
var mc = cClusterIcon.cluster_.getMarkerClusterer();

google.maps.event.trigger(mc, "click", cClusterIcon.cluster_);
google.maps.event.trigger(mc, "clusterclick", cClusterIcon.cluster_); // deprecated name
```

to this:

```
var c = cClusterIcon.cluster_;
var mc = c.getMarkerClusterer();

google.maps.event.trigger(c, "click", cClusterIcon.cluster_);
google.maps.event.trigger(c, "clusterclick", cClusterIcon.cluster_); // deprecated name
```

That's it!

Don't forget to change both markerclusterplus scripts (`markerclusterer.js` and `markerclusterer_packed.js`). After you make the edit, you can recreate the `_packed.js` version using [UglifyJS](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl//uglifyjs) by cut n' pasting it into this site. I already used that and it works great (30.6% of original).

For details on how to fix the `'mouseover'` and `'mouseout'` events in that script, see my other [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589958/how-come-the-mouseover-and-mouseout-events-for-markerclustererplus-js-are-not-fi).

Comment: I have the latest 2.1.2 version with all your code implemented in there but still cannot catch `click` or `clusterclick` event :(

Comment: For me 'clusterclick' works good. I used markerclustererplus.

Answer (score 1):

I find this solution with jquery-ui-gmap.

```
var clusterer_ = $('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'MarkerClusterer');

google.maps.event.addListener(clusterer_, 'clusterclick', function (cluster) {
   alert("cluster click event");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using MarkerClustererPlus, just attach the event listener to the google maps `addListener` method:

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {options});

google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, "click", function (c) {
    console.log('Cluster Object:' + c)
});
```