# How come the mouseover and mouseout events for MarkerClustererPlus.js are not firing for my cluster?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, mouseover, mouseout, markerclusterer

The `mouseover` and `mouseout` events are not firing for the MarkerCluster class as per the [MarkerClustererPlus documentation](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html). I even tried stuffing it in the `clusteringend` event as I noticed you need to wait for this before doing anything else with the clusters, but no luck.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(arrLocLatLng[0], arrLocLatLng[1]),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var arrMarkers = [
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(myLat1, myLng1)
    }),
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(myLat2, myLng2)
    })
];

var mcOptions = {gridSize: 50, maxZoom: 15};
var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, arrMarkers, mcOptions);

// need to wait for clusteringend, otherwise clusters may not be in DOM
google.maps.event.addListener(mc, 'clusteringend', function () {

    var arrClusters = mc.getClusters(); // will just be one

    // THIS IS NOT FIRING
    // Event name: mouseout
    // Event args: c:Cluster
    // Event Desc: This event is fired when the mouse moves out of a cluster marker.
    google.maps.event.addListener(arrClusters[0], 'mouseover', function ()
    {
        alert('mouseover event triggered on this particular cluster);
    });

    // ALSO NOT FIRING
    // Event name: mouseover
    // Event args: c:Cluster
    // Event Desc: This event is fired when the mouse moves over a cluster marker.
    google.maps.event.addListener(arrClusters[0], 'mouseout', function ()
    {
        alert('mouseout event triggered on this particular cluster);
    });
});
```

Comment: Where did myCluster come from? Where is it defined?

Comment: @Marcelo - good catch. Typo, That should be `arrClusters[0]` instead. Updating...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. There's a bug in the markerclusterer.js file version 2.0.15 as of 1/29/13.

In the MarkerClusterer.js file (non-packed version), change this:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_, "mouseover", function () {
    var mc = cClusterIcon.cluster_.getMarkerClusterer();
    /**
     * This event is fired when the mouse moves over a cluster marker.
     * @name MarkerClusterer#mouseover
     * @param {Cluster} c The cluster that the mouse moved over.
     * @event
     */
    google.maps.event.trigger(mc, "mouseover", cClusterIcon.cluster_);
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_, "mouseout", function () {
    var mc = cClusterIcon.cluster_.getMarkerClusterer();
    /**
     * This event is fired when the mouse moves out of a cluster marker.
     * @name MarkerClusterer#mouseout
     * @param {Cluster} c The cluster that the mouse moved out of.
     * @event
     */
    google.maps.event.trigger(mc, "mouseout", cClusterIcon.cluster_);
});
```

};

to this:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_, "mouseover", function () {
    var c = cClusterIcon.cluster_;
    /**
     * This event is fired when the mouse moves over a cluster marker.
     * @name MarkerClusterer#mouseover
     * @param {Cluster} c The cluster that the mouse moved over.
     * @event
     */
    google.maps.event.trigger(c, "mouseover", cClusterIcon.cluster_);
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_, "mouseout", function () {
    var c = cClusterIcon.cluster_;
    /**
     * This event is fired when the mouse moves out of a cluster marker.
     * @name MarkerClusterer#mouseout
     * @param {Cluster} c The cluster that the mouse moved out of.
     * @event
     */
    google.maps.event.trigger(c, "mouseout", cClusterIcon.cluster_);
});
```

... and it will work.

Comment: don't forget to change your script to use the non-packed version (`markerclusterer.js`) to verify the fix.